# How to deploy app with firebase hosting without a index.html?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-ssr

I don't have a index.html file, the app is React SSR, which built with just an index.js entry file. To start the server I do `node index.js`.
How do I deploy the app in firebase?

Comment: Have you tried a few articles from Google? There's a lot of information out there: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-and-firebase-are-all-you-need-to-host-your-web-apps-f7ab55919f53

Comment: I did. It has a index.html file. So firebase takes a html file. Unless I use a cloud function. That's where I am stuck, cause I couldn't figure out how to use it with cloud function, cause I just have to replicate something like ```node index.js```.